# Why do $r \mid (p-1)$ and $p \mid (r^3-1)$ imply $p \mid (r^2+r+1)$ for primes $p, r$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $r, p$ prime such that $r \mid (p-1)$ and $p \mid (r^3-1)$. Why does it hold that  $p \mid (r^2+r+1)$?

(This is from the [writeup](https://ctftime.org/writeup/9905) of a cryptography challenge where the author made that statement without further explanation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
$$
p\mid r^3-1=(r^2+r+1)(r-1),
$$
hence either $p\mid r^2+r+1$ or $p\mid r-1$. Can we have both $p\mid r-1$ and $r\mid p-1$?